# Error : Index out of bounds of array

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

```
 string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\myname\Desktop\test.txt");
        int cnt = lines.Count();

        int arraynum1 = 0;
        int arraynum2 = 1;
        int arraynum3 = 2;

        try
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < cnt; x++)
            {
                mc[0] = lines[arraynum1];
                mc[1] = lines[arraynum2];
                mc[2] = lines[arraynum3];

                arraynum1 = arraynum3 + 1;
                arraynum2 = arraynum3 + 1;
                arraynum3 = arraynum3 + 1;

                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new[] { mc[0], mc[1], mc[2] });
                listView1.Items.Add(item);

            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Whenever I use my variable `cnt` in the `for loop` to specify which line to stop at, I receive the error listed in the title of this question, but whenever I set an `integer` in place of `cnt`  in the loop it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your file contains 6 lines, this would be the values your mc[0]..mc[2] would hold inside your for loop:

Iteration 1 (x=0):

```
mc[0] = lines[0]
mc[1] = lines[1]
mc[2] = lines[2]
```

Iteration 2 (x=1):

```
mc[0] = lines[3]
mc[1] = lines[3]
mc[2] = lines[3]
```

Iteration 3 (x=2):

```
mc[0] = lines[4]
mc[1] = lines[4]
mc[2] = lines[4]
```

Iteration 4 (x=3):

```
mc[0] = lines[5]
mc[1] = lines[5]
mc[2] = lines[5]
```

Iteration 5 (x=4):

```
The exception you stated will be thrown here
mc[0] = lines[6]
mc[1] = lines[6]
mc[2] = lines[6]
```

Iteration 6 (x=5):
    Will never be reached

So instead of increasing your loop var x by 1 increase it by 3 like:

```
        for (int x = 0; x+2 < cnt ; x+=3)
        {
            mc[0] = lines[x];
            mc[1] = lines[x+1];
            mc[2] = lines[x+2];

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new[] { mc[0], mc[1], mc[2] });
            listView1.Items.Add(item);

        }
```

This approach will also consider the possibility that your file won't contain number of lines which isn't divideable by 3.

Comment: Probably worth removing `arraynumX` altogether.  It looks like it's only being used to track the `lines` index to use, which your solution doesn't use.

Comment: Ahh, should've refreshed before commenting. :)

Comment: @MrBlue:you right for my answer I somehow miss `<`.  I think it is the best approch for this solution. What I don't understand the votes up for other answer.

Comment: I think some people just skimmed the question and didn't realise the OP is trying to read 3 lines per iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't it be

```
    arraynum1 = arraynum1 + 1;
    arraynum2 = arraynum2 + 1;
    arraynum3 = arraynum3 + 1;
```

instead of

```
    arraynum1 = arraynum3 + 1;
    arraynum2 = arraynum3 + 1;
    arraynum3 = arraynum3 + 1;
```

Comment: that would work but i need all the arrays to be one higher than the arraynum3 and continuously go through and add up, im getting strings from a text file and storing them in the array and thats how im doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
arraynum1 = arraynum1 + 1;
arraynum2 = arraynum2 + 1;
arraynum3 = arraynum3 + 1;
```

as you are currently referring to the same array arraynum3 in all the three cases.

```
arraynum1 = arraynum3 + 1;
arraynum2 = arraynum3 + 1;
arraynum3 = arraynum3 + 1;
```